Instead of returning post content, return code that I specify
I created custom post types called funds.  My page has over 200 of them.  After buiding the page the back end payment processor changed the way they want to display the form for donating.  It is now a pop up.  So, instead of having to re-do everything, I am hoping to write some wp_query code that will instead of taking a user to the fund (CPT) page on click, it will display the code that I specify per fund.  I need help writing the wp_query code.
The page I am working on is this:  https://catholicfutures.org/give-online/
Scroll down to the bottom where all of the funds are shown.  I have already set up all of the functionality to be able to query and filter these 200+ funds.  So, I am hoping to be able to just change the query rather than start all over.

What is that, an archive page? And the plan is to pop up a form on that page instead rather than opening the separate fund page?

I guess you already have custom scripts on the page to run the filter? I'd guess it's simplest to use that to hook the on clicks for the funds at the bottom and do something else, which I guess is going to be to load your code blocks from a new AJAX endpoint or a new REST endpoint instead.

This is just a regular page on the website with the objective of giving people the opportunity to donate to funds that they are passionate about.  It used to go to a CPT blog page that had a unique form for each fund.  Now, the payment processor wants us to use pop-up.  So, rather than return the CPT blog page, I just need the click to open the pop-up.
